# How to prevent spam answers on questions that ask about products but are borderline recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation

How should the community handle this question, and those like it, in order to avoid spam or one-liner answers:  [How do I select project management software for our current workflow?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6324/need-suggestions-for-project-management-software)

### **My Thought Process:**

- It appeared to be and off-topic tool recommendation, but the op included plenty of detail and described the problem he/she was trying to solve, so I left it alone to see where it would go.
- The question got at least 1 really outstanding, detailed answer, possibly 2, IMHO.
- Today, the question gets two borderline spam/definitely spam one-line "non-answers".  (See the [FAQ - How to Answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) and the [FAQ - Deletion](https://pm.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) section.)
- Based on discussions [here](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/351/34) and [here](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/why-does-our-policy-on-pm-tools-appear-inconsistent), product recommendations are *definitely* off-topic **unless there is a clear problem to be solved, which I feel like there is.**

These questions traditionally attract spam. I edited the question to also ask for an explanation of how to use that tool effectively in hopes this will reduce more spam-type answers.

For an answer to *really* be effective, it should include an explanation, kind of like how [JohnJ's answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/6327/34) and [eMgz's answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/6326/34) explain how to use the tool effectively.  Those two answers are good examples of what answers to this question should look like.

### **Options After Editing:**

- Downvote, comment, improve, or delete low quality answers.

Anyone with 125 rep can downvote. Anyone with 15 rep can flag answers. Those who have 4000 reputation on this site **can vote to delete answers with a score of -1**.

I feel like this is a great example of a question where our community can perform actions to make this a great contribution to the site.

Voting on questions and answers, as well as using your editing powers, close votes, delete votes, comments, are critical for crowdsourced quality control.

We all get 30 votes per day (and 40 votes if 10 of them are used on questions). Let's use these tools to celebrate the great content and encourage improvements or removal of content that's not so great.

**Here are our [top voters for the month of August](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=month).**

Did I miss anything?  What else can we do to help askers on our site ask great questions and get great, spam-free answers?